# Аrping on windows

Tags: python, windows

I have different devices on the same IP address, how to organize a function on windows in python like in Linux "`arping -i eth0 192.168.0.250`" which shows mac addresses on this IP address?

Comment: Why do you have multiple devices on the same ip address? That's just a mess.

Comment: This is for setting up IP camera that come with one IP address, and if there are a large number of them, let's say 100 pieces, then it is not convenient for them to manually set IP addresses.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/arp.html